# Eclipse problem : the selection can not be launched, and there are no recent launches

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a newbie with Java and trying to write a very simple program like this ofcourse

```
public class FirstProg {
public static void main( String[] args) {
    System.out.println(" I am learning how to code");
    System.out.println("Today's date is");
}}
```

When I ran it, it said to me that, `the selection can not be launched, and there are no recent launches` , I ran it on Eclipse. Could you please give me some ideas? I am a newbie and very confuse with this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by launch? Did you click on the run button? or `Ctrl+F11`?

Comment: If this is your complete code then you are missing `}` at the end to complete class definition

Comment: Before you execute your code, make sure that there aren't any errors. If the message persists, you should probably specify your main class.

Comment: Sanjeev: Sorry for my missing, I copied my code from my book so that I thought that the code was ok
SandeepKumar: yeah I click the run button and it show me that problem. And I am very confuse with this

Comment: Right Click on the file and select 'Run As > Java Application'

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to be exact, because we don't know exactly what you've clicked on, or what version of eclipse you have. Eclipse is very flexible, and one result of that is that it does not have the same subwindows and buttons for every user.

There is a standard 'view', i.e., a subwindow within Eclipse's main window, called "Project Explorer. It is most often on the left side of the eclipse window, and displays folders and files in one or more projects.

Find the folder for your project in that view, right-click on it, and look for the options "Run As..." and "Debug As...". Those are also menus, they will have options that depend on how your eclipse is configured. But one of the options should be "Java Application", which is the right one for what you're doing. "Run As..." runs your program; "Debug As" runs it under the eclipse debugger.

If there is only one Java class in the project with a `main(String[] args)` method, then eclipse will run that class. If there's more than one such class, it will ask you to choose.

Once you've done this, there are usually buttons on the top of eclipse; one is an insect-looking icon, the the other a triangle with a point to the right -- the first is 'debug', the second is 'run', and once you have debugged or run a class, clicking on one of those will debug or run the last class you debugged or ran.

Good luck.